# Detect Content Type by Name JS

Tags: 2013, content-type, guid, newform

I have some javascript running behind my NewForm.aspx. I would like to modify a Choice field based on the Content Type being used. I can determine the Content Type by checking the parameter:

```
GetUrlKeyValue('ContentTypeId')
```

But I'm assuming this GUID will change once I move to production. So instead of hard coding this check, is there a more reliable way to get the current Content Type through JavaScript? Say, by name and not GUID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below JavaScript

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");

var listContentTypes = oList.get_contentTypes();
clientContext.load(listContentTypes);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onFailed));

function onSuccess(sender, args) {    
    var e = listContentTypes.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
        var ct = e.get_current();
        if (ct.get_name() == "ContentTypeName") {
            alert(ct.get_id());
            break;
        }
    }
}

function onFailed() {
    alert('Request Failed');
}
```